# How to exit from a "do-while" loop?

Tags: c

I'd like to know what's the best way to exit from a do-while loop without using EOF or another number.
Is there a way to enter a character so that the user can exit the loop?
I've tried writing `printf("Enter a number ('x' to exit):` but it doesn't work.
Do you know another method?
I can't use EOF because otherwise the program won't count -1 as a number and the number -1 will be used exclusively to exit the loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int even(int number);

int main(){
    int n;
    do{
        printf("Enter an integer (x to terminate): ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        if(n=='x'){
            break;
        }
        printf("%d\n", even(n));
    }while(n!='x');
    return 0;
}

int even(int number){
    if(number%2==0){
        return 1;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: The best way to exit a dowhile loop is to make the condition fail. Please rephrase your question to explain why this is not a solution for your problem. Providing some example code would be helpful, so that you and potential answerers can look at the same thing while discussing. This is especially important, because you imply some construct in your question which however are not detailed, e.g. some way of input...

Comment: @Yunnosch The user must enter a integer. If I use EOF (-1) then -1 is not counted as an integer.

Comment: Please provide the non-working code.

Comment: Do not describe code. Show it. Otherwise I feel forced to answer something cynical like "in line 5 of your code, replace the `char` with `int`".

Comment: @jxh I've provided it.

Comment: @Yunnosch I've written the code

Comment: Just enter the number 120, just like you programmed. :-)

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Interesting but also quite cynical angle. I think however that you could make an interesting AND helpfully friendly answer. It would provide an interesting partial answer and if it is understandably written I guess it could be worth upvoting.

Comment: I think Yunnosch's answer is most useful. If OP tries my suggestion and is intrigued enough to learn more, that's great; by mostly I just wanted to be snarky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep the return value from `scanf()` like in

```
 int scanreturn=0;
 /* ... */
 scanreturn= scanf("%d", &n);
```

Then use this as condition for the do-while

```
}while (scanreturn == 1);
```

This works because `scanf()` returns the number of successfully scanned input fields.
That will be 1, as long as one integer was successfully scanned.
When "x" is entered, or anything not looking like an integer, the loop will end.

Compare https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf

> Return value:
>    Number of receiving arguments successfully assigned (which may be
>   zero in case a matching failure occurred before the first receiving
>   argument was assigned), or EOF if input failure occurs before the
>   first receiving argument was assigned.

Or quoting from C standard 7.21.6.4, e.g. http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.4

> ... the scanf function returns the number of input items assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero, in the event of an early matching failure.

Answer (score 0):

```
int n, val=1;

do{
    printf("Enter an integer (x to terminate): ");
    val=scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("%d\n", even(n));
}while(val!=0);
```

[Scanf()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-10/) returns number of items successfully read.

You can do this too:

```
int n;
char c[25];

do{
    printf("Enter an integer (x to terminate): ");
    scanf("%24s", c);
    printf("%d\n", even(atoi(c)));
}while(c[0]!='x');
```

Comment: Can you quote something, to support your description of scanfs return value?

Comment: `scanf("%s", c)` is dangerous and may overflow the buffer.
`atoi` is not able to differentiate between error and 0.

Comment: @Yunnosch just check the link [Scanf](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm)

Comment: @Inrin I don't think, just check the value range of int, you never use more than 25

Comment: Yes I checked it, and I think that site confused  return values of scanf and printf.

Comment: @Yunnosch you right, I  just wanted to put a website to support my code and chose the worst haha

Comment: My respect for how you handle my critc.

Comment: @FábioMorais `scanf("%s", c)` does not care how big your buffer is.
So an attacker could make the typical buffer overflow attack. (Many sources online).
Use `scanf("%24s", c)` instead. `24` as the maximum field width does not include the terminating null byte.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of ways to go with this.

`scanf` returns the number of successful conversions and assignments.  If you're expecting a single decimal integer input and the first thing you see is `'x'`, then you have a *matching failure*, and `scanf` will return 0.  So, you can do something like

```
printf( "Gimme a number: " );
if ( scanf( "%d", &n ) == 1 )
{
  // do something with n
}
else
{
  if ( !feof( stdin ) )
  {
    // user entered something that isn't a decimal digit
  }
  else
  {
    // EOF signaled on input stream (ctrl-D, ctrl-Z, EOF from redirected file, etc.).
  }
}
```

The problem is that this leaves unmatched input in the stream to foul up the next read.  A better solution IMO is one that reads everything as text, then uses `strtol` to convert the text to an integer.

```
#include <stdlib.h> // for strtol
#include <ctype.h>  // for isspace

#define MAX_INPUT_LENTH 13 // enough for 10 decimal digits plus sign plus newline plus string terminator

char input[MAX_INPUT_LENGTH+1];

printf( "Gimme a number: " );
if ( fgets( input, sizeof input, stdin ) )
{
  char *chk; // will point to first character in input that *isn't* a
             // decimal digit
  int tmp = strtod( input, &chk, 10 );
  if ( !isspace( *chk ) && *chk != 0 )
  {
    // input is not a valid decimal integer
  }
  else
  {
    n = tmp; // don't assign n until you know you have valid input
  }
}
else
{
  if ( feof( stdin ) )
  {
    // end-of-file signaled on input stream
  }
  else
  {
    // error during input
  }
}
```

Neither of these solutions are in a loop, but you should be able to figure out how to integrate them into a looping structure.